# Python Deep Learning find Duplicates

Tags: python, deep-learning

I want to try and learn Deep Learning with Python.
The first thing that came to my mind for a useful scenario would be a Duplicate-Check.

Let's say you have a customer-table with name,address,tel,email and want to insert new customers.
E.g.:

```
In Table:
Max Test,Teststreet 5, 00642 / 58458,info@max.de
To Insert:
Max Test, NULL, (+49)0064258458, test@max.de
```

This should be recognised as a duplicate entry.

Are there already tutorials out there for this usecase? Or is it even possible with deep learning?

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate matching is a special case of similarity matching. You can define input features as either individual characters or fields and then train your network. It's a binary classification problem (true/false) unless you want to have a similarity score (95% match). The network should be able to learn that punctuation and whitespace is irrelevant and an 'or function' for at least one of the fields matching to produce true positive.

Sounds like a fairly simple case for deep learning.

I don't know of any specific tutorial for this, but I tried to give you some keywords to look for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `duplicates=dataset.duplicated()`

It will return all rows which are duplicate

Then:

`print(sum(duplicates))`

to print count of duplicated rows.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, finding duplicates for numbers and category data should be simpler. The problem arises when it is free text. I think you should try out fuzzy matching techniques to start with. There is good distance metric available in Python called Levenshtein distance. The library for calculating the distance is python-Levenshtein. It is pretty fast. See if you get good results using this distance metric if you want to improve further you go for deep learning algorithms like RNN, LSTM, etc. which are good for text data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem to find duplicate instances in relational database is a traditional research topic in database and data mining, which is called "entity matching" or "entity resolution". Deep learning is also adapted in this domain.

Many related works can be found in google scholar by searching "entity matching"+"deep learning"

Answer (score -1):

I think that it's easier to build some functions, who can check different input schemes than training a network to do so. The hard part would be building a large enough data set to train your network correctly.